# Error build Angular Universal

Tags: angular, angular8

Compañeros una consulta estoy usando angular universal pero al hacer el " npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr" me arroja este error y no encuentro solucion alguien se a enfretado a esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Pudiste resolverlo? Trata de ejecutarlo desde `cmd`. En algún momento tuve problemas con MINGWen windows relacionado a algunas rutas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que aparece en consola esta relacionado a el objeto windows, dicho objeto no existe del lado del servidor, únicamente del lado del cliente (browser).

Te dejo este enlace donde explican lo que te comento.

https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/docs/gotchas.md